# CQRS in a Rails environment?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongodb, database-design, architecture, nosql

I'm trying to wrap my head around CQRS (Command Query Response Separation) per Martin Fowlers recent post at:

http://martinfowler.com/bliki/CQRS.html

Given a project:

```
Main Database (Postgres):
  Product has many Sales
  User has many Sales

Reporting Database (NoSQL - Mongodb)
  Transaction (A Product and a Sale and a User)
```

And a requirement of producing a chart of transaction dollars per day for a given month.

- What controllers would I need for reporting?

  - A Reports controller for views and partials
  - A Graphs controller for pulling the specific info for a graph out of the Reporting DB?
- What the heck would the DTO (Data-Transfer Object) be in this case?
- Is this really CQRS?

  - I assume so, since Reports/Graphs created from reporting DB would not be changing state, just a view on the main DB?

Thanks!

Comment: You might want to read this, too: http://www.udidahan.com/2011/04/22/when-to-avoid-cqrs/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're still interested in investigating CQRS with Rails have a look at [rcqrs](https://github.com/slashdotdash/rcqrs) a Ruby CQRS with Event Sourcing library I created.

There's also a [Rails 3 plugin](https://github.com/slashdotdash/rcqrs-rails) to integrate with your Rails app that comes with generators to ease common tasks for creating commands, events and controllers using the CQRS pattern.

Finally, there is a very simple sample blog Rails application to look at how you might use CQRS with Rails (look at my GitHub account for more details).

Comment: I can also heartily recommend Luismi Cavallé's presentation ["the CQRS diet"](http://www.slideshare.net/cavalle/the-cqrs-diet) for a step through guide to applying CQRS to a Rails application from the basic principles.

Answer (score 2):

I guess you need read more about CQRS first, before try apply it. Because of CQRS is not Command Query Response Separation but Command and Query Responsibility Segregation.

I suggest to start reading from Greg Yuong [cqrs info](http://cqrsinfo.com/documents/) and any articles about cqrs by [Udi Dahan](http://www.udidahan.com/2009/12/09/clarified-cqrs/) and Martin Fowler as well. And after that take a look on exists implementations of cqrs.

With cqrs you usually will have two databases: Read and Write. 
Write database is usually normalized store. Read database -- database that will contains data in denormalized form to minimize the number of joins needed to get a given set of data.

Comment: Yes, you're correct I mixed up the name.  Thanks for the references, but that doesn't really get to my core problem of whether the implementation I mentioned qualifies as CQRS, and the role of DTO in it.

Comment: Your CQRSInfo link is semantically broken. It's not a correct link because the domain was hijacked. We have some guidance at architecture.jayway.com.